# In Go, how to determine offset of slice within an array?

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

I know that `a1` is a slice within array `a`. Is it possible to determine offset of `a1` with respect to beginning of `a` (basically emulating pointer arithmetics)?

```
a := [...]int8 {3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2}
a1 := a[3:14]
fmt.Println(a1, "has length", len(a1), "and offset", /*offset(a1,a)*/)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
a := [...]int8{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2}
a1 := a[3:14]
fmt.Println(a1, "has length", len(a1), "and offset", cap(a)-cap(a1))
```

The expression `a[p:e]` returns a slice with capacity equal to `cap(a) - p`. Given the slice `a1` and backing array `a`, you can compute p as `p = cap(a) - cap(a1)`

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/23GQbuZxBQ)</kbd>

Comment: Notice that this only works if you don't change the capacity during slicing.

Comment: Neat. For symmetry, it could be `cap(a)-cap(a1)`