# Offsetting zero index in Golang slice

Tags: go

In C, we can move pointer like so:

```
int main()
{
    int array[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int *q;
    q = array; 
    printf("%d\n", q[0]); /* 1 */
    q += 3; 
    printf("%d\n", q[0]); /* 4 */
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Golang?

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types - it's not at all the same, but now that the question is already closed, there's no way to add a proper description of using slices to get the effect you want.

Comment: @torek I have tried to do it in my answer.

Comment: @PumpkinSeed: what the OP might want is: `q := arr[:]` followed by `q = q[3:]`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/29110426/1256452

Answer (score 3):

Golang does not support pointer arithmetic since that is a source of vulnerabilities.

References: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Answer (score 1):

Golang does not support `pointer arithmetic` in order to increase the safety during development.

Answer (score 1):

For example, using Go slices,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    array := [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    slice := array[:]
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", slice[0]) /* 1 */
    slice = slice[3:]
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", slice[0]) /* 4 */
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/82pXFkHLSfd

Output:

```
1
4
```